# MDX Count scoped to current context date

Tags: mdx

I want my MDX query to calculate the number of days an employee has worked for Full day.

The measures are Hours and Attended Hours, while dimensions are Employee and Calender Date. I am not sure how can I modify this query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[IsPresent] as IIF([Measures].[Hours] >= [Measures].[Attended Hours],1,0)
    MEMBER [Measures].[CountOfDays] as DISTINCTCOUNT(EXISTING FILTER([Calender Date].[Calender].[Date], [Measures].[Hours] >= [Measures].[Attended Hours]))

    select {[Employee].[Number].[Number].ALLMEMBERS} on 0, {[Measures].[CountOfDays]} on 1 from (
        SELECT ({[Employee].[Number].[Number].ALLMEMBERS},{[Measures].[Hours],[Measures].[Attended Hours]}) ON 0
        , { [Calender Date].[Calender].[Date]}on 1
        From (select {[Calender Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2016-01-01T00:00:00] : [Calender Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2016-01-31T00:00:00]}  ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [BJ Cube]  WHERE ([Calender Date].[Is Work Day].&[Y]))
    )
```

A sample dataset is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAu0w.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Does the following MDX work for you?

```
MEMBER [Measures].[CountOfDays] as
SUM( 
    existing [Calender Date].[Calender].[Date].Members,
    IIF(
      [Measures].[Hours] >= [Measures].[Attended Hours],
      1,
      NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: Calculated members are not subject to auto exist in MDX hence this member wont filter data for the criteria [Calender Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2016-01-01T00:00:00] : [Calender Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2016-01-31T00:00:00]

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please specify your problem?